# Visual Studio - Copy User Controls to New project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I make new project and trying to add existing item(*User Control*) it does not work. It splits *User Control* into **3** files(`cs`, `Designer.cs` and `resx`) not one.

Any chance to add existing user form into project without making library or something.

Comment: That is quite normal and needn't stop you from reusing it.

Comment: How can I copy then my User Controls? There must be the way?

Comment: Copy all three files I'd say..

Comment: I tired, and they are separated all the time, it wont merge them in control.

Comment: Of course they will not merge. VS needs them as separate files with separate functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding only the [UserControl].cs to the project.
VS should detect the related files ([UserControl].Designer.cs, [UserControl].resx) and add them to the [UserControl].cs automatically.

Comment: All add great, but won't add designer.cs and code breaks. :/

Comment: @Softouch Try dragging the [UserControl].cs AND [UserControl].Designer.cs from your (Windows) File Explorer into your VS Project (Solution Explorer). VS should NOT be run as admin for this.

Comment: It works I think. Only if you adding One by One .cs UserControl file. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+Alt and select User.cs